# php & CURL - how to

Tags: php, curl

I am "playing" with an idea, but it might use curl which I am not too sure about, but can fathom my way round most.  I can curl a page and get the contents - that's OK, but can you curl a page and get "specific" contents say a variable string or array?  Reason for asking is I do a lot of updating to a few sites but most of that is "common" and it now makes sence to only do the updates once and then have the sites curl them.

Comment: In a cURL you're just getting the server to do a HTTP request, so you'll get all the content of the page. Will need to parse and find what you want from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

weird
use an RSS feed instead of that nonsense with HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get content with cURL and then use Regular Expressions to extract exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Or use SOAP or any other WS implementation to centralize your content management system

Answer (score 0):

I second the RegExp approach, and another solution could be the Dom parser: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php